# function that takes a function as argument and returns a new function

Tags: functions, funcall

I'd like to write an elisp-function that has a function as argument and returns a new function.

Let's say the new function `double-the-function` should write the returned value of the argument-function twice.
(The argument function operates on a string and returns a string. This is ensured.)

So:

`(reverse "abc")` returns: `"cba"`

If I define the function `f` as follows:

`(setq f (double-the-function reverse))`

I expect that:

`(f "abc")` returns `"cbacba"`

which is equal to `(concat (reverse cba) (reverse "cba"))`.

How to define `double-the-function`?

Comment: If you *quote* the function symbol (i.e. `'reverse` ) when you pass it as an argument, then `double-the-function` can simply use `funcall` to call its argument as a function. With this information, you can probably answer your own question.

Comment: Keep in mind that elisp is one of the worse languages to do FP in. While you can with some contortions, that's not what idiomatic code looks like.

Comment: @wasamasa Which langugage would you suggest? 
Most of the time I'm working with emacs that's why I have chosen elisp. I don't have to configure anything: I just open an .el-file and can code and test the code in the file itself. That's very easy for me.

Comment: Scheme, Racket, Clojure.  Alternatively one of the strongly typed functional languages like Haskell, Ocaml, F#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding : t -*-
(defun double-the-function (fn)
  (lambda (string)
    (let ((result (funcall fn string)))
      (concat result result))))

(funcall (double-the-function 'reverse) "abc")
```

Comment: You can do this to avoid using funcall: (fset 'f (double-the-function 'reverse))

(f "abc")